# I cannot find the datasource folder in my grails-app conf folder

Tags: grails, grails-orm

I am a beginner in Groovy and Grails. I read the documentation but after complete installation and app creation, i am unable discover the DataSource folder in the grails-app conf directory.

Comment: Where in the docs does it say anything about a DataSource folder?

Comment: nope. not if i am using just a text editor. it does only when i am using GGTS

Answer (score 0):

if you are using grails 3+, so that datasource config will be in application.yml.
If you are using grails 2+, so that datasource config will be in DataSource.groovy
There is no datasource folder as well.